# What is the English word for “team-building with playing video games”?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just a few days ago, I saw an article with a new word that when I Googled it, I found out that word meant "team-building with playing video games", but now I forgot it.

I wonder if anyone knows then maybe you could just let me know, what is the word? I still can't remember the word (my memory and my English is very bad) but I remember it was just one word.

Answer (score 1):

**Cooperative gameplay** is the first thing that comes to mind

> Cooperative gameplay (often abbreviated as co-op) is a feature in video games that allows players to work together as teammates, usually against one or more AI opponents.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still couldn't remember the word (my memory and my English is very bad) but I remember it was just one word.

Comment: 99.99% of all native English speakers will tell you they've never heard such a word, even if they believe it could exist. My view is they're at least 99.99% right.

If Google showed you such a word, how could it possibly have 'gone'?

Even beyond that, how do you think there could ever be a single word for a phrase like 'team building' let alone 'team building' combined with anything else, be it 'playing anything' or 'video anything' or 'games anything'?

Nice try and if someone invented such a word, anyone else understanding it would be a lot less than likey…

Comment: @FarzadJ This seems like a long shot but are you referring to "gamification"? The definition is a little different, but it is a slightly uncommon word that often connects business and video games.

Comment: I think “cooperative gameplay” has become a real term, but it does not refer to what the OP is asking - team building exercises at work or school that use video games. CG is used within the context of vide games, to describe what kind of game it is. Just like football is a team sport whereas singles tennis isn’t that kind of a sport.